# orchard query content items by translation

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

i have a query which returns content items from the Orchard db

```
return _orchardServices.ContentManager.Query<EventTypePart, EventTypePartRecord>()
            .OrderBy(eventType => eventType.Name);
```

what I would like to know is is there a way to returns items by language or translation.
So for example only give me event records localized as german?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried; However you `Content Types` get a `LocalizationPart` attached in order to achieve it. 
Check `Orchard.Localization`, this is a query from its Service :

```
_contentManager.Query(content.ContentItem.ContentType)
.Where<LocalizationPartRecord>(l => l.MasterContentItemId == content.ContentItem.Id && l.CultureId == cultureRecord.Id)
```